# Postfix favors non virtual to virtual host

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a linux user thomas and 2 domain names domain1.com and domain2.com. I have followed steps to have two virtual mail boxes `/var/mail/vhosts/domain[12].com/`

When I test and send an email to thomas@domain2.com, it lands in `/var/mail/vhosts/domain2.com/thomas/...`

When I send it to thomas@domain1.com, it lands in /var/mail/thomas. However, `dovecot` looks into `/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n`. How can I fix that ?

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` to help you better.